# BeautifulSoup - How do I get the document that pressing a button delivers?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape my banking website to automatically download the pdf that is produced from the purchases throughout the month. I am able to log in and get to the page where the button is, however, the button isn't just a link, I think it is an API call possibly, but I can't see anything in the inspector underneath **Network** when I click the button. Is there any way to get this document using BeautifulSoup? or will I have to use something like Selenium?

Here is the code I am using to get to the webpage,

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib
import dropbox
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

J_USERNAME = "usernamewithformatting"
USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"
SECRET_WORD = "word"
FILENAME = "filename.csv"

API_KEY = "aaaaaaaaaa"

prescreening = {
    'j_username': J_USERNAME,
    'reset': "true",
    'username': USERNAME
}

cookies = {
     cookies: "cookies"
}

login = {
    loginInformation: "Login Information"
}

header = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/...'
}


ROOT_URL = "https://www.centralbank.net"
LOGIN_URL = "https://secure.centralbank.net/..."
ACTIVITY_URL = "https://secure.centralbank.net/..." 



def main():
    with requests.Session() as s:
        result = s.post(ROOT_URL, data=prescreening)
        home = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login)
        activityPage = s.get(ACTIVITY_URL)
        print('Username entered code: ', result.status_code)
        print('Login entered code: ', home.status_code)
        print('Activity loaded code: ', activityPage.status_code)
```

Here is what the webpage button looks like that I am trying to access,
[webpage button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iCmq.png)

Here is what the inspector says about the button,
[HTML Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7L3B.png)

The resulting PDF from clicking the button is a new webpage that has a URL similar to,[this link](http://%20https://secure.centralbank.net/api/accounts/57...3b/activity/attachments.pdf?attachment-type=activityPDF&service-key-hash=3ca...9&accountType=DDA&accountKey=55...3b&start-date=2021-01-31T00%3A00%3A00.000-0600&end-date=2021-03-02T23%3A59%3A59.999-0600&hasFilters=false&quickSearch=30&specificSearch=false&sort-column=transDate&sort-order=desc&show-balances=Y&pending=N)

And the webpage is similar to printing from a webpage,
[button result pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85I46.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that pdf download link is generated by `JS` so you won't scrape it with `bs4` as it simply won't see it in the source HTML. You might be better off exploring `selenium` or check if the bank has an API.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't have an API so I'll check out selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered my question by using selenium to bypass the JS. For anyone in the future dealing with web scraping selenium is quite simple and worked really well for my project.